# RecyclerView and OnDragListener

Tags: android

I am currently trying to get a on drag listener working with my staggered grid view recycler view.

I might as well ask this before I go any further: Should the OnDragListener be applied to the RecyclerView inside my fragment or to the individual views inside of static ViewHolder class (example:  `public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnDragListener`).

The goal of the on drag listener is ultimately so I can rearrange the items in my staggered view.

I haven't seen any tutorials or any hints of the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Put listeners on the items, which are in your grid view. This way, you know where you have to drop your view, too.

Comment: Can't edit(5min rule): So, your second approach should fit. But be aware to track ACTION_DRAG_EXITED on your gridView, since your items will drop away otherwise.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re ok so I will apply on drag to individual views and set listeners also?

Comment: That's how I've done it and it works like charm. But as said, you have to be aware of the borders if you remove items at onDrag, so that your users won't drop the items outside of your gridView and the items are gone.